# Redefining values to FilenameFilter in Java

Tags: java, io, filefilter

I have files present in a Directory with the format `ddMMyyyyhhmmss` (for example `190420120533481146Wj.jpeg`).  I am trying to pick only latest 10 files from this directory .

Now as you can see I am searching the file names by using the substring (`1904201212`) of the current date.

For example :

```
Actual Date :19042012121306
Subs value :190420121213
```

As you can see in the below program, I am starting my search with the current date minute value.  If there aren't any files for the current date minute value,

- I want to redefine my search to current date hour value, and if there aren't in that case
- I want to further redefine it to current date value, if not found,
- Redefine it to previous days like that.

---

```
public class Raa {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        File myDir = new File("C:\\");
        String res = new Raa().getTime();

        System.out.println(res);


        String substring = res.substring(0,12);
        System.out.println(substring);

        FilenameFilter select = new FileListFilter(substring);

        File[] contents = myDir.listFiles(select);

        for (File file : contents) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
          }
         }

    public String getTime()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
        Date curDate = new Date();
        String strDate = sdf.format(curDate);
        return strDate;

    }
}
```

How can we continuously redefine searches programatically?

Comment: If what you're interested in is the latest 10 files, why don't you simply store the files by their date, and then take the last ten files of the list?

Comment: Ya , i am already storing files  with the current time stamp , but how do i pick the latest 10 files ??

Comment: As I said, by sorting the files by their date, and then take the last 10 files. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much , there will be a performance issue here , there might be 10,000 images or more  present and i cant use sort .

Comment: A sort has n * log(n) complexity. If you need to go to the third day before today, your algorithm needs 5 * N operations, and then you need to sort the results anyway. I tested my algorithm and it takes 66 milliseconds to sort an array of 10000 Strings formatted like you said. Make it work first. Optimize only if necessary. 10000 is nothing for a computer.

Comment: jb-nizet, sort could be sufficiently fast but this requires IO.

Comment: If performance is a concern you may maintain list of top files and update it as long as new file is created. Depending on requirements that list could consist of links in a separate directory or in memory.

Alternatively you may group files by date into sub-folders year/month/day so there is no necessity to scan whole list every time (and not all types of file systems handle directories with large number of files well).

As a side note, the date format in file name is not optimal (year is in the middle) since just sorting by name will not work.

Comment: I don't see how it requires more IO than your algorithm. You have to get the list of files in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the list of files is to use File.listFiles() and as documentation states that there is no guarantee about the order of the files returned. Therefore you need to write a Comparator that uses File.lastModified() and pass this, along with the array of files, to Arrays.sort().

> File[] files = directory.listFiles();
>
> Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator(){
>
> ```
> public int compare(File file1, File file2)
> {
>     return Long.valueOf(file1.lastModified()).compareTo(file2.lastModified());
> }
> ```
>
> });

Once you get the list of files then only fetch the first 10 elements in the array.